# If X and Y are two sets of vectors in a vector space V, and if X $\subset$ Y, then is span X $\subset$ span Y?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification, span

If X and Y are two sets of vectors in a vector space V, and if X $\subset$ Y, then is span X $\subset$ span Y? **If so, why is or isn't the span of X a subset of the span of Y?**

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the hints!
Here is the proof I came up with; **please let me know if it is correct.**

The spanning set of X can be written as:
Span(X) = {$a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + ... + a_n x_n$} where all $x_i$ are vectors and all $a_i$ are scalars.
Since X$\subset$Y then all $x_i$ are also in Y.
Thus, Span(x) is a linear combination of vectors from Y
So Span(x) $\subset$ Span(Y).

Comment: Hint: Take an arbitrary element in span $X$, write it's expansion in terms of $X$, and sneak in the remaining vectors in $Y$ into the linear combination without altering the vector.

Comment: Well, even if $X$ is a proper subset of $Y$ it may be that $SpanX=SpanY$.  For example $X=(0,1)$ $Y=\{(0,1),(0,2)\}$.

Comment: $X \subset Y \subset \text{span}\ Y$, so $\text{span}\ Y$ is a linear subspace of $V$ which contains $X$. Since $\text{span}\ X$ is the **smallest** linear subspace of $V$ which contains $X$, it follows that $\text{span}\ X \subset \text{span}\ Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Every linear combination of elements of $X$ is also a linear combination of elements of $Y.$

Comment: Nice! You beat me by $6$ seconds :) +$1$ for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** A linear combination of elements in $X$ is already a linear combination of elements in $Y$.